# How to calculate the feedback resistors for an SMPS

Tags: resistors, switch-mode-power-supply, feedback

[image]

I have designed an SMPS circuit for my host board. As the datasheet, the feedback resistors are calculated as

[image]

As per the datasheet, Feedback Voltage(Vref) is 0.6V and I want 4V Output Voltage. Therefore, feedback resistors are chosen like below after the calculation.

R15 = 5.6K

R17 = 1K

I measured the output voltage from the board; it is 1.2V.

I also measured the feedback voltage and it is 0.6V, same as in the datasheet. So, what can be the problem? Am I doing something wrong? Calculations were done with an oscilloscope.

(I can not add the datasheet link as I don't have enough reputation. The SMPS regulator is L7986 from STmicroelectronics.)

Update1: I changed feedback resistors to get the 4V output by changing the resistors ratio. Measured output was 1.2V with initial resistors. So I changed the resistor rate by multiplying it with 2.3 (4/1.2V) to get 4V output. After this change, the output voltage is about 7.8V. I had thought that I can get the desired output voltage if I modify the ratio of feedback resistors. So, any thoughts?

Update2: I guess I broke the regulator while trying to measure the output voltage with an oscilloscope. I don't know what caused this, but now the regulator outputs the input voltage directly to the output pin. I was very careful with the connections, I just connected it to voltage supply as the same before and measured voltages from the scope.

Comment: What does "I also measured the feedback voltage and it is true." mean ? Do you see 0.6V or do you something else ? If so, what ?

Comment: *But when I tried to measure the output voltage from board, It was calculated as 1.2V* That is a confusing sentence. Do you mean: *I measured the output voltage, it is 1.2 V* ?

Comment: 1) The feedback resistor values look OK to me. 2) It would help if you linked to a datasheet of the switcher IC you're using. 3) just because the output voltage is incorrect, **do not assume** that the feedback circuit is wrong. There can be plenty of other reasons why this circuit is not behaving as expected.

Comment: @FakeMoustache ,efox29 Thanks for answers. Yes, I measured the output voltage from board, it is 1.2V and I also measured the feedback voltage from board, it is 0.6V. [Here](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00041568.pdf)
is the datasheet for IC

Comment: I double checked the board for short circuits, there is no problem with that. I'm new with regulators and power circuits, I wanted to ask if there is another problem that I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify the things we've asked about. It makes it easier for new readers to understand your question if they don't have to read through all the comments to get the whole picture.

Comment: You are right, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: It's also important to know if you measured with an oscilloscope or a multimeter. If you have a lot of oscillations, the voltage you measure with a multimeter can be pretty much anything.

Comment: Edited again, I measured it from oscilloscope. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: OK, some more remarks/questions: what inductor are you using ?  A type which is recommended in the IC datasheet ? Is your circuit is loaded by any other circuits ? If so, then disconnect these if possible and check the voltage again. Did you follow the PCB layout guidelines in the datasheet of the IC ?

Comment: I have disconnected all load components from the power circiut. Output current is in normal states and I checked my formula from the example values in datasheet; the calculation is true. I have also calculated the voltage ratings and inductance&capacitance values according to calculations, recommended in datasheet. Here is the inductor datasheet: [link](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1635217.pdf)

Comment: I updated my question with a new result.

Comment: Sounds like you made a mistake in your first test and the 5.6K was actually 1K, or the 1K was actually 5.6K. Are you using parts with markings?

Comment: I tested it with 2 boards and resistors are in smd package, i checked markings and also measured resistance values. But they were true :/ I was actually wondering whether i am missing a huge thing as i am little beginnery with power circuits.

Comment: Take an oscilloscope measurement of the switching node (pin 8) and post it. Put some load on the supply and do it again. Show both the startup characteristic and a closeup of the static-state switching.

Comment: I updated the question again. I had seen the duty cycle on output pin, but after that I guess the regulator is broken down for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle for the feedback resistors is, that it is a voltage divider.  With 5.6k and 1k as shown, the junction between them will show a voltage based on the ratio of R17 and the total.  5.6k+1k is 6.6k, so the result is 1k/6.6k, or 0.15.  That means that with 4 volts applied, the junction will be 4 * 0.15 or .6 volts.

The regulator (when it's working properly) will adjust the output voltage up or down until it sees .6 volts on the feedback (FP) pin.  You can test this by placing a somewhat higher resistance across R15 or R17.   10k would work here.  If you put it across R15, the voltage at the junction will rise, and the regulator will lower its output voltage to compensate.  Likewise, putting it across R17 will lower the feedback voltage, and the regulator will raise the output voltage to compensate.  If you get no reaction, you have a different problem.  Sometimes the supply/regulator has got the voltage as high as it can go, but in that case, the voltage on FB would be correspondingly low.

And sometimes, the resistors are just wrong, or there's a miswiring, or there's stray resistance somewhere (like a shorted capacitor).  But the basic voltage divider principle can't be violated. There's always another explanation.